# Difference between --cacert and --capath in curl?

Tags: ssl, curl, ssl-certificate

When would one use the `--cacert` option vs. the `--capath` option within `curl` (CLI that is).

`--cacert` appears to reference a monolithic file that contains multiple PEMs.  Assume it scans through to find the matching hostname?

`--capath` appears to reference a directory in which multiple files live.  Does curl pick up the appropriate certificate as a filename therein?

Answer (score 58):

From the [docs](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

> --cacert (HTTPS) Tells curl to use the specified certificate file to verify the peer. The file may contain multiple CA certificates. The
>   certificate(s) must be in PEM format. If this option is used several
>   times, the last one will be used.
>
> --capath (HTTPS) Tells curl to use the specified certificate directory to verify the peer. The certificates must be in PEM format, and the
>   directory must have been processed using the c_rehash utility supplied
>   with openssl. Certificate directories are not supported under Windows
>   (because c_rehash uses symbolink links to create them). Using --capath
>   can allow curl to make https connections much more efficiently than
>   using --cacert if the --cacert file contains many CA certificates. If
>   this option is used several times, the last one will be used.

So, if you specify --cacert, the CA certs are stored in the specified file. These CA certificates are used to verify the certs of remote servers that cURL connects to.

The --capath option is used to specify a directory containing the CA certs rather than a single file. The c_rehash utility should be used to prepare the directory i.e., create the necessary links. The main benefit of using --capath would appear to be that it's more efficient than the 
--cacert single file approach if you have many CA certs.

Here's a script that probably does what c_rehash does:

```
for file in *.pem; do ln -s $file `openssl x509 -hash -noout -in $file`.0; done
```

With both options you should be careful to only include CA certs from CAs you trust. If for example, you know the remote servers should always be issued with certs from YourCompanyCA, then this is the only CA cert you should include.

Comment: Why more efficient?  Because it can lookup the cert via the filesytem name?

Comment: @Xepoch Yes, I think it creates files with the hash of the subject name of each cert and then links these hash files back to the original cert. This makes lookups faster. I've added a small script that probably does what c_rehash does to perhaps make it clearer.

Comment: Since Ubuntu has a ca certificate directory, if I want to download the most recent ca-bundle.crt from Curl Haxx website, then what should I be doing? Just dropping the file into the directory and running that command? Or is there some ubuntu specific configuration required?

Comment: 2018 Update: The `--capath` option apparently now is supported on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows you can run the following as a batch file and pass in the capath folder name:

c_rehash.cmd:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
if \%1\ EQU \\ goto :usage
pushd %1
if NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 goto :usage
del *.0
for %%I in (*.pem) do call :hash %%I
popd
goto :eof
:hash
for /F "usebackq" %%J in (`openssl x509 -in %1 -hash -noout`) do mklink %%J.0 %1
goto :eof
:usage
echo Usage:
echo.
echo Rehash a folder of x509 Certificates for Curl
echo.
echo %~n0 ^<Folder^>
```

Example:

```
c_rehash c:\cacerts
```