# Facebook - error Callback verification failed: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: facebook, ssl

When setting up a callback URL in "Canvas payment" / "Realtime Update Subscriptions" I get the following error:

> Callback verification failed: SSL certificate problem: unable to get
>   local issuer certificate

When I click "test callback url"

The website open fine, it's only Facebook which makes problems.

The only answer I found ( [curl: (60) SSL certificate : unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611640/curl-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate) ) did not solve the problem.

Comment: Check your callback URL against [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and look for problems like a incomplete certificate chain.

Comment: Thanks, indeed there are intermediate CA missing

Comment: @Konrad I have the same problem. I have the "intermediaries certificate code", but I don't know where to place the code. Do you know what extension is this file?