# PHP curl_exec returns blank with no errors

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

Hey guys i'm trying to make a curl request to facebook Graph API, but when i use $curl_exec it returns nothing.

My code:

```
 $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, BioCommandController::getGraphUrl(). $this->{self::AD_ACCOUNT_ID}.'/offsitepixels?'.$fields_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $return = curl_exec($ch);
```

curl_getinfo() response:

```
    Array
    (
    [url] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/ MY DATA
    [content_type] =>
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 1
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.031
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0.016
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] =>
    [primary_ip] => 2a03:2880:f005:1:face:b00c:0:1
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 443
    [local_ip] => 2804:7f5:f180:dc6d:c5e5:3e79:d447:d583
    [local_port] => 54603
)
```

I'm new to Curl so i have no idea how to interpretate the getinfo response, also i have tested my graph api resuqest on my browser and it works, it returns what i need! And also even if i was generating something weong on my graph API request Facebook always answers something for example:

> {
>      "error": {
>         "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
>         "type": "OAuthException",
>         "code": 2500
>      }
>   }

Does anyone know whats going on? I can't seem to figure it out, thanks!

### UPDATE

id runed this code (So u can really know what's going on wwith curl)

```
if ($return === false) { die(curl_error($ch)); }
```

and i got this:

> SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Comment: `if ($result === false) { die(curl_error($ch)); }`. have curl TELL you what went wrong. "blank" doesn't mean it's really empty. boolean falses print as zero-length strings.

Comment: Thanks, ive tried that i got this: "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"  i'll try to find out how to fix it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hey guys this is how i solved my problem:

> Relating to 'SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate' error. Rather obviously this applies to the system sending the CURL request (and no the server receiving the request)
>
> 1) Download the latest cacert.pem from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
>
> 2) Add the following line to php.ini (if this is shared hosting and you don't have access to php.ini then you could add this to .user.ini in public_html)
>
> curl.cainfo=/path/to/downloaded/cacert.pem

[curl: (60) SSL certificate : unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611640/curl-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)