# Curl err (60) SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I would like to connect to some API by SSL.

Already I have generated 5 files:

```
PROD.cert.pem
PROD.issuer.pem
PROD.chain.pem
PROD.csr
PROD.key
```

This is my php code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,           $wsdl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT,       getcwd() . '\PROD.cert.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, getcwd() . '\PROD.key');

$output = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump(curl_errno($ch));
var_dump(curl_error($ch));
```

So, as you can see I add two files: cert and key

When, I run this code I always got error:

```
SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Do you know, what I do wrong? How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611640/curl-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate?

Comment: have you set path of `cert.pem` file in your `php.ini`

Comment: Yes, I have set path co cert.pem

Comment: Should I use PROD.issuer.pem file anywhere ?

Answer (score 0):

Certificates are not be included in your webdir, you need to install them on your webserver. You can find a comprehensive guide [here](http://slacksite.com/apache/certificate.php)