# SSL verification behind McAfee Proxy on LAMP VM

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl, vagrant, lamp

I've been trying off and on to get a LAMP development server operational behind my corporate firewall (McAfee Web Gateway). I have a Ubuntu/Trusty64 image on a virtualbox VM provisioned through Vagrant.  I cannot get "some" {most} repositories to load for a proper `sudo apt-get update`.  I'm getting a 401 authentication required error on all *'security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/*'* sources and *'archive.ubuntu.com trusty/*'* sources and all fail to fetch.  Therefore most all `sudo apt-get install {whatever}` fails and I cannot add the necessary PPA repository to install the LAMP environment I want.

I can turn off SSL verification for some things and can get many things installed - but I need SSL working correctly within this environment.

Digging deeper, I find that if I `curl -v https://url.com:443`, I get the

> curl(60): ssl certificate error: unable to get local issuer certificate.

I have the generic bundle 'ca-bundle.crt' installed locally in /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ and ran `sudo update-ca-certificates` which seemed to update ca-certificates.crt in etc/ssl/certs/.

I ran a `strace -o stracker.out curl -v https://url.com:443` and searched for the failing stat() as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611640/curl-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate) by No-Bugs_Hare and found that `curl` was looking for 'c099e901.0' in /etc/ssl/certs/ and it isn't there. Googling that particular HEXID is no joy and am stuck at this step.

Next I tried `strace -o traceOppenSSL.out openssl s_client -connect url.com:443` to see if I can get more detail but can't see what causes the

> verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate

followed by two other errors (I'm sure all relating to the first one), then displays the "Server Certificate" within a BEGIN / END block, followed by a bunch of other metadata. The entire session ends with

> Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate).

So, this is not my forte and I'm doing what I can to try and get this VM operational.  Like I said earlier, I've been trying many things and understand most of the issue is the fact that I'm behind a McAfee firewall within my corporate structure. I don't know how to troubleshoot more than what I've explained above but I'm willing to dig deeper.

I have a few questions. Why is curl looking for that particular hex ID and where would I find or generate the beast? Are there other troubleshooting steps I should try? The VM is a server-class Ubuntu install, so I only have a SSH CLI terminal and no WindowManager GUI to work with this.