# Amazon SES error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, ssl

I'm trying to set up and test Amazon SES on my local. I installed `daniel-zahariev/php-aws-ses` version. I set up a send.php to test with the following code:

```
<?php

require_once 'src/SimpleEmailService.php';
require_once 'src/SimpleEmailServiceMessage.php';
require_once 'src/SimpleEmailServiceRequest.php';


$m = new SimpleEmailServiceMessage();
$m->addTo('MYEMAIL@EMAIL.COM');
$m->setFrom('CSMGR@EMAIL.COM');
$m->setSubject('Hello, world!');
$m->setMessageFromString('This is the message body.');

$ses = new SimpleEmailService('MY ACCESS KEY', 'SECRET KEY');
print_r($ses->sendEmail($m));
```

Whenever I run send.php I receive the error:

> SimpleEmailService::sendEmail(): 60 SSL certificate problem: unable to
>   get local issuer certificate in 
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\amazonses\src\SimpleEmailService.php on line 392

The email address I'm using are both verified. New to Amazon SES so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The issue is actually an underlaying `cURL` problem within the SES framework. [You can read more about it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611640/curl-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER from your curl code. To disable change following code in SimpleEmailServiceRequest.php file getCurlHandler function.

```
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```