# Self-signed certificate issue on setup webhhok for Facebook-messenger bot application

Tags: node.js, windows, openssl, ssl-certificate, facebook-messenger

I get this error when i tried to set webhook url for facebook messenger bot:

> The URL couldn't be validated. Callback verification failed with the following errors: curl_errno = 60; curl_error = SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain; HTTP Status Code = 200; HTTP Message = Connection established

First i created certificate.

1) I used [this config file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anders94/https-authorized-clients/master/keys/ca.cnf) and  created certificete authority:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 9999 -config ca.cnf -keyout ca-key.pem -out ca-crt.pem
```

2) I generated a private key

```
openssl genrsa -out server-key.pem 4096
```

Then i generated certificate signing request using [this configuration file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anders94/https-authorized-clients/master/keys/server.cnf)

```
openssl req -new -config server.cnf -key server-key.pem -out server-csr.pem
```

After that i executed command:

```
openssl x509 -req -extfile server.cnf -days 999 -passin "pass:password" -in server-csr.pem -CA ca-crt.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -out server-crt.pem
```

I didn't chnage any property in configuration files.
Then installed my certificate on windows server by [this way](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~gsw2c/GridToolsDir/Documentation/ImportTrustedCertificates.htm)

On my Node.js app i created https server using this options:

```
var server = https.createServer({
    ca: fs.readFileSync('sslcert/ca-crt.pem', 'utf8'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server-key.pem', 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server-crt.pem', 'utf8')
}, app); server.listen(port);
```

And when i tried to set webhook i got above error. If i open my webhook url on browser i am getting

```
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

if ignore this error application console shows status 200

Answer (score 1):

That's right, the URL couldn't be validated because your self signed certificate is in the certificate chain. This is expected behavior.

Self signed certificates are fine for just encrypting the connection, but they don't convey the other important part of proving third party validation that the provider is who they say they are, which is what validation is.

You'll need to get a cert that carries this validation to validate your callback URL. You can purchase one from a reputable vendor, or you can use a service like [StartSSL](https://www.startssl.com/) to get one for free (I'm not associated with them in any way, I've just had good experience with them).

Answer (score 1):

You follow [THIS](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/ssl/install-lets-encrypt-to-create-ssl-certificates) and use [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) after that you will get these four files
1.cert.pem
  2.chain.pem 
 3.fullchain.pem 
 3.privkey.pem 
**chain.pem** is CA file.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611640/curl-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/39502013#39502013) I also have written a small code snippet to use these.

Comment: Thanks Ravi, I will take a look of the step to see if it work well