# Ssl certificate error: unable to get local issuer certificate on wamp in magento 2

Tags: php, windows, configuration, magento2, php-openssl

I'm getting SSL certificate problems: `unable to get local issuer certificate` error when connecting to Magento marketplace using WAMP. Please tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

thanks it fixed

I downloaded the .pem file https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and then input this line in php.ini:

{curl.cainfo=/path/to/downloaded/cacert.pem}

In /setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/MarketplaceManager.php

change this: protected $urlPrefix = 'https://'; into protected $urlPrefix = 'http://';

This is really a modification of a core file, so avoid this method if you can solve the problem with a certificate.

Update: In 2.1.x the file to edit is /setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/PackagesAuth.php

Comment: Fiddling around with core implementation is not advised - this lowers the chances that your future upgrades can be deployed smoothly. Changing from `https://` to `http://` is a hack and does not require setting up the CA file anymore... I suggest to revert back to Magento's original state and use proper secure transport instead

Comment: Besides that, if you question has been answered (either by my previous answer or your own), please vote for it and mark your question as solved. Thx

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there's no certification information available on your windows system. This answer might solve the issue you experienced:

[curl: (60) SSL certificate : unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611640/curl-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate#answer-31830614)