# Gravity Forms Podio Integration Error

Tags: php, wordpress, integration, podio

I'm trying to connect to Podio using Gravity Forms. I've generated an API key and added it on a Podio Integration field. However, upon authentication, I'm getting a PodioConnectionError.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PodioConnectionError' with message 'Connection to Podio API failed: [60] SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate' in /home/content/80/5825280/html/SITE_2017/wp-content/plugins/gravityformspodio/includes/podio-php/lib/Podio.php:261 Stack trace: #0 /home/content/80/5825280/html/SITE_2017/wp-content/plugins/gravityformspodio/includes/podio-php/lib/Podio.php(107): Podio::request('POST', '/oauth/token', Array, Array) #1 /home/content/80/5825280/html/SITE_2017/wp-content/plugins/gravityformspodio/includes/podio-php/lib/Podio.php(68): Podio::authenticate('authorization_c...', Array) #2 /home/content/80/5825280/html/SITE_2017/wp-content/plugins/gravityformspodio/includes/api/class-gfp-podio-api.php(121): Podio::authenticate_with_authorization_code('d390f383048b45f...', 'https://powerfu...') #3 /home/content/80/5825280/html/SITE_2017/wp-content/plugins/gravityformspodio/includes/class-gfp-podio-addon.php(396): GFP_Podio_API::finish_server_authentication('gravity-forms-p...', in /home/content/80/5825280/html/SITE_2017/wp-content/plugins/gravityformspodio/includes/podio-php/lib/Podio.php on line 261

Did anyone experience this issue before?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to generate a public and private certificate pair it looks like. Simply having an API key does not secure the channel.

Comment: Thank you @Shawn! But how do I get the certificate pair? Should I ask my client about this?

Comment: If you are using SSL then you will probably need to upload a public cert to the podio and keep the private key on the server. I would be surprised if Podio does not have documentation on this.

The general formula is to generate your keys that encrypt the SSL connection, however in order to trust the connection Podio needs to verify it is you with your public key. Does this make sense? In the case of what you posted you have an authentication API key but that does not secure the channel. The keys encrypt (and sign) the traffic.

Comment: (Addendum) This can also be done with any generic shared secret as well. For example is there a place to send along a long security string? Can you post some code and the type of authentication you are doing?

Comment: Hi @Shawn, sorry for the late response. I just generated a Podio API key as instructed after installing the Podio extension for Gravity Forms.
You can view the screenshot here: 
(https://i.imgur.com/L8kDzSZ.jpg)
(https://i.imgur.com/yhHL0cN.jpg)

Then after clicking the Authenticate button, that's where I'm getting the said error.

Let me know if that makes sense.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Shawn's advise, I managed to solve this issue by following the provided solution on this question: [SSL certificate error: unable to get local issuer certificate when authenticating with Podio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41083951/ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-when-authenticatin)

I used this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-settings/ and added the following codes inside the field.

```
curl.cainfo = "/path-to-server/cacert.pem"
openssl.cafile="/path-to-server/cacert.pem"
```

I hope this will help others in need.

Thanks!