# PHP script results in Missing required redirect uri error

Tags: php, google-api, composer-php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I've been going at this for about an hour and a half now and I just can't seem to figure out composer! I'm trying to install the Google APis php client library so that I can access the calendar api.  I am following [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php#prerequisites)

I think everything is set up correctly but when I get to the final step PHP quickstart.php git bash gives me these errors. (BELOW)

[image]

This is my file structure (BELOW)

[image]

By the way I do have the autoloader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message has nothing to do with composer

> Missing required redirect uri

Redirect URI is set in the Google developer console for your project it should also be included in the JSon file you downloaded.  You should go back to your tutorial and check Step 1: Turn on the Google Calendar API. you missed something in there.

Comment: You were right I gave it the wrong name it sent me a link and i copied the code but after entering the code it give me this error.... also I can't upload files in a response so I'm going to give you a gyazo and I will be uploading real pictures in the future. https://gyazo.com/28beaabf561b15227552e555714fea67

Comment: Have you tried reading the errors you are getting?  That is a different error now that is a ssl error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611640/curl-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate   If you cant figure that one out I suggest you open another question.   Its best to keep to one issue per question.

Comment: Alright I'll do that also thanks for helping with the first one.

Comment: I am not going to be much help with the other one anyway that's a curl error I have very little experience with curl.