# can't solve file_get_contents() warnings

Tags: php, api, file, warnings, file-get-contents

This is my code so far, I have three different file_get_contents() warnings all for the definition of the $response variable here they are,

1. SSL operation failed with code
2. Failed to enable crypto, and
3. (https://api.imgur.com/3/image): failed to open stream:

I've used the curl requests(commented out), which solved the warnings but, I had to change the definition of $response, which I don't intend to do.

```
<?php
include_once("connect.php");

    class Image
    {
        public static function uploadImage($formname,$query,$params)
        {       
            $image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES[$formname]['tmp_name']));
            $options = array('http'=>array(
                'method'=>"POST",
                'header'=>"Authorization: Bearer access code\n".
                "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                'content'=>$image
            ));

            $context = stream_context_create($options);
            $imgurURL = "https://api.imgur.com/3/image";
            if ($_FILES[$formname]['size'] > 10240000) {
                die('Image too big, must be 10MB or less!');
            }

            $response = file_get_contents($imgurURL, false, $context);
            $response = json_decode($response);


            $preparams = array($formname=>$response->data->link);
            $params = array_merge($preparams,$params);

            connect::query($query,$params);                

        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: What are the exact warnings you are getting?

Comment: they're in the description

Comment: No, you just have a summary of them. Paste the actual warnings as PHP displays them.

Comment: ok, 1.Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in C:\wamp64\www\image.php on line 38

Comment: 2.Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in C:\wamp64\www\image.php on line 38

Comment: 3.Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.imgur.com/3/image): failed to open stream: operation failed in C:\wamp64\www\image.php on line 38

Comment: Which version of PHP do you have installed?

Comment: 7.0.10 and 5.6.25

Comment: You probably need to follow the instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-and-more/28701786#28701786. I haven't tested this, but you'll probably have to add the `ssl` array element in that answer to your existing `$options` array. You'll also probably need to download the `cacert.pem` file, which you can find more details about here (including a download link): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611640/curl-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/31830614#31830614

Comment: how would I nest the array I tried this:                                                                        $options = array('http'=>array(
                'method'=>"POST",
                'header'=>"Authorization: Bearer access code\n".
                "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                'content'=>$image)
         'ssl'=>array(
        "cafile" => "/path/to/bundle/cacert.pem",
        "verify_peer"=> true,
        "verify_peer_name"=> true
        )
    );               but i got a syntax error for adding the element

Comment: Looks like you're missing a comma after the first array. Try this `$options = array('http'=>array( 'method'=>"POST", 'header'=>"Authorization: Bearer access code\n". "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 'content'=>$image), 'ssl'=>array( "cafile" => "/path/to/bundle/cacert.pem", "verify_peer"=> true, "verify_peer_name"=> true ) );` Also make sure you swap out the value of `cafile` with the real path to the `cacert.pem` file. You can download it and put it pretty much anywhere, just make sure you reference the path correctly. For example: `C:\curl\certificates\cacert.pem`

Comment: ok, now I just have the third warning, Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.imgur.com/3/image): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Permission Denied

Comment: is there a specific place where I have to put the command in the php.ini file?

Comment: At this point the original issue is resolved & the HTTP request is working, but you're not authenticating with the Imgur API correctly. You need to read this & implement the OAuth protocol: https://api.imgur.com/oauth2. This means swapping out the `Authorization` header in your `$options` array with the correct access token. Also read this and make sure your POST body has the correct structure: https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/image. Also, you need to use `\r\n` instead of `\n` as the line ending character of the header line. This is probably beyond the scope of Stack Overflow comments now...

Comment: what do you mean exactly by the correct structure of POST body?

Comment: Right now you're putting the base64 encoded image data directly in the `content` element of your `$options` array (as the POST request body). But based on the info [here](https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/image#image-upload), it looks like you actually need to use JSON format, and the encoded image goes in the `image` JSON key. But this is just a guess; I'm not very familiar with the Imgur API. I still think your main issue is the [OAuth described here](https://api.imgur.com/oauth2), based on the 403 response code you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

The extension `php_openssl` must be enabled on your server.

Call `phpinfo()` and check the section `openssl` is present and `OpenSSL support` is set to `enabled`.

Additionaly, verify that you have installed the common certificates on your server. If your are on linux and Debian/Ubuntu, you can do `apt-get install ca-certificates`.

Comment: all of these things check out fine but how would write that command if I'm on windows?