# Success & Error: curl: (60) unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: bash, ssl, curl, https

I´m doing some curl request on my web application (also on bash) and recogonized the following behaviour:

Sometimes i´m doing a

```
 curl --header "ApiKey: an1ceke3y" https://test.host.com/api/endpoint
```

i get the following:

```
 curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

But sometimes, even a second after the fail request i made an successful request.

I made a little test with 6 requests:

```
1) Success
2) Error
3) Success
4) Success
5) Success
6) Error
```

Shouldn´t the

```
unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Happens all the time?
Is there a way i could better debug the issue?

**Additional informations:**

API Endpoint is behind a microsoft azure load balancer

Success Request ( with -v )

```
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
```

Error Request ( with -v )

```
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [curl: (60) SSL certificate : unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611640/curl-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Comment: @Aserre but why it success sometimes? The other posts are about perm failures.

Comment: Is it possible that  your app is running in multiple servers behind a load balancer which is not handling SSL  termination?

Comment: @Tiago: Do you mean the endpoint URL? Thats possible -i will ask the customer.

Comment: Also use the verbose flag for `curl` `-v` that may give you more info.

Comment: @Tiago added further informations with -v output

Comment: @develth, take a look at the output of curl with `-v`, does it  always use the same ip address? don't paste the ip address, just asking because you may have round robin dns and could be using one or more load balancers. if it's not the case chances are that SSL termination is handled at the server behind the load balancer.

Comment: @Tiago already checked it. The Hostname resolves to the same IP address. Customer will check it with azure. Thanks!

Comment: same here, sometimes it works, sometimes not. Still trying to figure out for days. Any other possible solution?

Comment: @EugeneWang it was a config issues with the LB - one Server didn´t got updated with the new certificate.

Comment: @EugeneWang Did you resolve the issue? I am getting this inconsistant issue in my docker container in local machine. So I tried xampp instead of docker. Issue was there too.

Comment: @develth Is there a chance that this issue occur in docker? If you have any clue about it please share.