# Unable to use curl in PHP having custom headers and some data

Tags: php, api, curl, cloudflare

I am using cloudflare's API to manage my website and it's documentation says this-

```
curl -X POST "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/023e105f4ecef8ad9ca31a8372d0c353/dns_records" \
 -H "X-Auth-Email: user@example.com" \
 -H "X-Auth-Key: c2547eb745079dac9320b638f5e225cf483cc5cfdda41" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 --data '{"type":"A","name":"example.com","content":"127.0.0.1","ttl":120,"proxied":false}'
```

And the PHP code i have tried is this -

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/92g6wwa3794g8wsf040s9t12a511a3/dns_records");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'{"type":"A","name":"example.com","content":"127.0.0.1","ttl":120,"proxied":false}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'X-Auth-Email: email@mail.com',
'X-Auth-Key: bf1f67fdjbdkhwois56465813fcdb7',
'Content-Type: application/json'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $server_output;
?>
```

It is working on Actual hosting but not working on localhost.
But i am getting empty result,
What i am doing wrong in this?

Comment: What does `curl_error` give you? http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: it gives me this - "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate".@fubar

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611640/curl-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate || will this help..

Comment: @fubar it is still displaying same problem

Comment: Sorry, I just re-read and it sad local. It looks like there are lots of similar issues on SO. I'd suggest you look at the solved questions for that error, as that's all I'd be doing to help you further.

Comment: most likely its an old, fixed bug with OpenSSL. upgrade your curl & openssl dlls, and the ssl error should go away. i've seen that error countless times with the solution being to update libcurl & openssl