# CURL Tableau Rest API

Tags: api, curl, tableau-api

I am trying to execute below CURL command related to "Download Workbook" end point of Tableau Rest API. I am basically trying to download particular workbook and save it some location.

curl "http://MY-SERVER/api/3.1/sites/9a8b7c6d-5e4f-3a2b-1c0d-9e8f7a6b5c4d/workbooks/1a1b1c1d-2e2f-2a2b-3c3d-3e3f4a4b4c4d/content" -X GET -H "X-Tableau-Auth:12ab34cd56ef78ab90cd12ef34ab56cd" > c:\files\my-workbook.twbx

But the CURL command gives below problem

Curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Can someone please confirm if similar implementation is done? Downloading Tableau workbook and saving to particular shared location?

Thanks

Comment: I have added curl --insecure command and dont see any error. But can't see particular workbook made available in given location like M:\Tableau

Comment: Is your Tableau Server configured to use SSL?

Comment: Hi Talvalin, Yes that's correct, When i remove this "> M:\Tableau\Tag%20Periodical.twbx" part from the script then workbook xml is displayed on command line. also keeping this part shows me below data but no workbook                                                                                                 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  249k  100  249k    0     0   212k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  212k

Comment: Possible duplicate of [curl: (60) SSL certificate : unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611640/curl-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)