# how to integrate easily docusign api in symfony project

Tags: php, api, symfony, docusignapi

I try to use the docusign api in my symfony project. I followed the php sdk documentation.

I want to call the api to create enveloppe and send document.

```
public function signatureRequestFromTemplate(){
    $username = 'myUsername';
    $password = 'pswd';
    $integrator_key = $this->integratorKey;
    // change to production (www.docusign.net) before going live
    $host = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2";

    // create configuration object and configure custom auth header
    $config = new DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
    $config->setHost($host);
    $config->addDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", "{\"Username\":\"" . $username . "\",\"Password\":\"" . $password"\",\"IntegratorKey\":\"" . $integrator_key . "\"}");

    // instantiate a new docusign api client
    $apiClient = new DocuSign\eSign\ApiClient($config);
    $accountId = null;
    try{
        //*** STEP 1 - Login API: get first Account ID and baseURL
        $authenticationApi = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\AuthenticationApi($apiClient);
        $options = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\AuthenticationApi\LoginOptions();
        $loginInformation = $authenticationApi->login($options);
    }
//........//
}
```

After this step i have an exception:

> Exception: API call to
>   https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information failed: SSL
>   certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

What i have to do? Or do you have a easily way to integrate this api with symfony?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're facing does not originate from your code but from your PHP setup using **outdated SSL root certificates**. The exception is pretty clear about this:

> Exception: API call to
>   https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information failed: SSL
>   certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

In order to resolve your problem you need to download a set of up-to-date root certificates and update your PHP configuration. The process is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31830614).

The exception should vanish as soon as you configure both `openssl.cafile` and `curl.cainfo` to point to an up-to-date set of root certificates.

Comment: thank you! I understood this exception. Now i have SSL certificate up-to-date but it doesn't work!!! I think it's not the good way to authenticate et send a document with docusign. I did not understood everything in the documentation. So i am searching an example code to do this with php.