# Laravel Firebase cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, ssl

I just installed Firebase on Laravel. But when I try to do any operation I get the message: `cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local certificate issuer (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html )`.
I followed the procedure described [here](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611640/curl-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate) but the problem does not disappear.
And for the installation of Firebase on Laravel, I followed the procedure of this [tutorial](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/firebase-realtime-database-laravel/) and this [document](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).
So even by downloading the last **cacert.pem** and modifying the line `;curl.cainfo` by `curl.cainfo = "C: \ wamp64 \ bin \ php \ php7.2.10 \ cacert.pem"` and restarting the server, it does not change anything, the problem persists.
Can someone help me? I am really starting to despair.

Answer (score 4):

You need to download the CA bundle from here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Once downloaded, save it to your `C:\wamp64\` directory, and then add the following lines to the bottom of your `php.ini` file:

```
url.cainfo="C:/wamp64/cacert-2019-01-23.pem"
openssl.cafile="C:/wamp64/cacert-2019-01-23.pem"
```

Finally, restart WAMP.

In addition to this, you can set the following cURL options (in case the above does not work due to a self-signed or bad SSL certificate):

```
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are serving your application with "PHP artisan serve" command, it means you are using PHP built-in webserver which means all your .ini file configurations will not affect your application. Use Wamp or Lamp to serve your Laravel application if you are in a local environment and follow Zishan Danish Neno's answer.