# cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

i installed new wamp server 3.1.3 and php version 7.0.29 is selected 
i have added this code in php.ini file

```
curl.cainfo ="C:/wamp64/bin/php/cacert.pem"
```

still getting 'cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611640/curl-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: File is present?

Comment: yes on this path "C:/wamp64/bin/php/cacert.pem"