# How to fix this error "Impossible to connect, please check your Algolia Application Id"?

Tags: laravel, algolia, laravel-scout

I have everything correct, as written at **laravel/algolia** websites.

I tried to read lot of documentations and tutorials about Laravel Scout installation, but still can't find solution.

I have everything correct in my settings and also APIs are correct but still getting this error:

> Impossible to connect, please check your Algolia Application Id.

Comment: Can you include some of your code? It will it easier for others to help out :)

Comment: reason was that I had my project on localhost, once I moved my project to digitalocean every apis started working.

Comment: But why does it fail on localhost? Saying you moved to digitalocean does not solve the problem. I am getting the same issue.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue (with Windows 10) and found this exception in the stack trace:

```
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

I found the solution for the error above in another [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611640/curl-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate):

> 1) Download the latest cacert.pem from
>   https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
>
> 2) Add the following line to php.ini (if this is shared hosting and
>   you don't have access to php.ini then you could add this to .user.ini
>   in public_html)
>
> curl.cainfo="/path/to/downloaded/cacert.pem"
>
> Make sure you enclose the path within double quotation marks!!!

It solved my problem, Laravel Scout is working fine after that. Hope this will help someone.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved, but I could not find this error in the stack trace, if anyone can share a screenshot of that, it can help.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently on the issue came from on wrong credentials, this can occurs providing the wrong Application ID or Admin API Key. Also the correct way to provide the credential on scout.php is :

```
'algolia' => [
'id' => env('ALGOLIA_APP_ID', ''),
'secret' => env('ALGOLIA_SECRET', '')
],
```

And then fill your credentials in your .env file.

I'd recommend you to run php artisan config:clear in case you have cached your configuration (which you shouldn't do in dev env).

Let us know if it solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks. Registered on  https://www.algolia.com/account/api-keys/ copied key to my .env and code is working!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and solved it like this

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear or config:cache
```

My assumption is, because Laravel always creates a cache in the config, every time we change some config, there must be another config that is broken or an error due to the cache that was created earlier.

But I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

I share with you my experience.

System was Vagrant Homestead with VirtualBox in Windows 10.

command used in CMD:

```
php artisan scout:import "App\Post"
```

command failed with:

```
Impossible to connect, please check your Algolia Application Id.
```

Logged into virtual box with vagrant ssh and gave it another try.

That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this by piecing together a bunch of different answers.

I'm using Laravel, and therefore Scout-Extended, as Algolia recommends. I was getting the above error but knew my APP ID and APP KEY was correct. In order to see the logs, to get a full picture of what was failing, I did the following.

1. In your Laravel project, `AppServiceProvidor.php`

```
public function boot()
    {
        // I added this line to enable debugging output in the terminal
        \Algolia\AlgoliaSearch\Log\DebugLogger::enable();
    }
```

2. I then re-ran `php artisan scout:reimport` in my terminal (you can probably run whatever command is failing for you. I just was failing here at the initial import stage). I could then see the error message in the stack trace that read:

> Retriable failure on xyz-dsn.algolia.net: cURL error 60: SSL
> certificate problem: self
> -signed certificate in certificate chain (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for
> https://XYZ-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/locations/settings?getVersion=2

A bit of googling later, I realize my issue is that my laravel config isn't using a SSL certificate.

3. You can easily solve this by navigating to this website https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem which will download a new SSL certificate

After download, move this file to whatever location you want.

Then, find the php.ini file you need to modify by running `php --ini` and following that path. Open the php.ini in notepad with admin priviliges, then add the following line to the php.ini file at the bottom or where the [curl] is located (the location doesn't really matter.

`curl.cainfo="your/path/to/the/certificate/file/cacert.pem"`

Save, and rerun your algolia command.