# Can't connect to Algolia with PHP

Tags: php, laravel, algolia

I work on a laravel project, and I want to use Algolia search .

I'm using Laravel 5.8 , PHP 7.3.2, MySQL 5.7 , also I tried to use Algolia with plain PHP gave me the same error .

The `Scout.php` file :

```php
'driver' => env('SCOUT_DRIVER', 'algolia'),
'queue' => env('SCOUT_QUEUE', true),
'algolia' => [
        'id' => env('ALGOLIA_APP_ID', 'MY-APP-ID'),
        'secret' => env('ALGOLIA_SECRET', 'MY-APP-SECRET'),
    ],
```

`.env` file :

```
ALGOLIA_APP_ID=MY-APP-ID
ALGOLIA_SECRET=MY-APP-SECRET
SCOUT_QUEUE = true
```

I double checked the values I entered as AppID and AdminID, I should be able to connect just fine , but it always says:

> Impossible to connect, please check your Algolia Application Id.

I can connect and update data just fine when using Node.JS

Comment: Did you check [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55488366/how-to-fix-this-error-impossible-to-connect-please-check-your-algolia-applicat)?

Comment: I checked it, actually for god's sake the certificate solution worked , seems that I was adding the location to the cert. incorrectly . if you post it as answer I could mark it .

Comment: Just answering because the other question doesn't have a selected answer. But this is a duplicated question, so I'm gonna flag it. Give the original author an upvote, this might gonna get closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix this error "Impossible to connect, please check your Algolia Application Id"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55488366/how-to-fix-this-error-impossible-to-connect-please-check-your-algolia-applicat)

Comment: @azeós yes this is a duplicate , but this one provide better explanation and a direct answe that really solves the problem , or if Moderators can approve the answer on the original post so people don't struggle around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just quoting another answer on SO: [How to fix this error “Impossible to connect, please check your Algolia Application Id”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56395533/1095101). Full answer there, just quoting the relevant parts:

> 1) Download the latest cacert.pem from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
>
> 2) Add the following line to php.ini (if this is shared hosting and you don't have access to php.ini then you could add this to .user.ini in public_html)
>
> curl.cainfo="/path/to/downloaded/cacert.pem"
>
> Make sure you enclose the path within double quotation marks!!!

Author: @Anthem.