# Sendy 'Error communicating with Amazon SNS API: There was a problem executing this request'

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, sendy

I am getting the error 'Error communicating with Amazon SNS API: There was a problem executing this request'
Anyone who has used Sendy and experienced the same error?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and after looking into it there was a certificate issue. CURL was returning the error "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate" but this wasn't being returned within the UI.

I then followed these instructions for getting it working: [curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611640/curl-60-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

To see if you have the same error as me you can modify the sendy code slightly to output this error: within /includes/helpers/sns.php, line 463 output the curl error i.e. add the third line below:

```
   $output = curl_exec($ch);
   $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
   print curl_error($ch);
```

reload the page, it won't be pretty, but if it's the same error as me you'll be able to fix it.

Comment: check your certificate file path and file permission and what the exact error message comes