# curl https inside docker return: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: docker, ssl, jenkins, curl, devops

I have a problem with cURL inside docker container jenkins-slave, when execute curl inside container get this error:

curl https://mytool.domain.com

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html 

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

- I have installed ca-certificate trough package manager
- added certificate.cer to /usr/local/share/ca-certificate
- executed command "update-ca-certificates"

I have tried to run curl with :

curl --cert certificate.cer https://mytool.domain.com, but get same error

whats wrong?

NB: outside container ssl work and no error is retrived

Comment: The domain might be setup wrongly. Check with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html). Apart from that not much help to your specific problem can be given since without knowledge of the actual domain there is nothing reproducible here

Comment: In particular the dupe answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67314867/ which explains you must use a filename ending in `.crt` not `.cer`